# Room return different entity in DAO

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I have a DAO

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

     @Query("SELECT * FROM user_entity")
     fun getAll(): List<UserEntity>

     @Query("SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM user_entity")
     fun getCombined(): UserCombinedEntity
}
```

The classes are

```
@Entity
data class UserEntity(
    @ColumnInfo
    val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo
    val name: String
)

data class UserCombinedEntity(
    val count: Int
)
```

But this gives me an error that

> A failure occurred while executing
> org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Can ROOM actually support this?

---

This is a minimal example of the problem. Of course `UserCombinedEntity` has more fields.

Comment: Your query for `getCombined()` is annotated with `@Quert` instead of `@Query`.  I that actually in your code or just a typo in your post?

Comment: Typo in post @BobSnyder.

Comment: Build failures normally show more info about the cause.  In the left pane of the Build Output window, check to see if there are any lines that are closed (arrow pointing to right).  If so, click on them to open and see more error output.

Comment: Thanks @BobSnyder. It didn't show a lot of information but I double checked everything and it makes sense that `count` has to be a `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit weird because the error provided by Kotlin is not very helpful. The solution is to make sure that `count` is a `var`.

```
data class UserCombinedEntity(
    var count: Int
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need Combined entity for int , it is more easy to return int.

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM word  ")

int getAllCount();
```

Comment: That is just an example. Of course I have more data than just an int.

Comment: try to notation UserCombinedEntity as an @Entity

Comment: `@Entity` does not help